# Facebook Page Load Concept

Tags: facebook-page

I know the page reload concept via ajax without page refresh.
But facebook pages reload through normal page load. but sidebar's not loading just reload content area.

How is it possible?

Advance Thanks friends

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Facebook and Github change there URL without reloading the page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7721874/how-facebook-and-github-change-there-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook uses [bigpipe](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919)

The general idea is to decompose web pages into small chunks called pagelets, and pipeline them through several execution stages inside web servers and browsers. It is implemented entirely in PHP and JavaScript.

Clicking and taking some action on a webpage initialize/executes a pagelet, response generates from iframe or from ajax as well. Read the response and show it to a small chunk, this will not refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are using the new [history.pushState](http://html5demos.com/history) functionality in HTML5.

Comment: Thanks friend , now i know html5 features by you. but i find another solution with pushState event .like to share with you. Check this Link http://pjax.heroku.com/